# List tags aligning on one row in Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

List are by default block elements. Why is the Materialize CSS code below aligns the two list tahs (logo and home) in one row?

```
<ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-menu">

       <li class="logo">
         <a id="logo-container" href="#!" class="brand-logo">
           <object id="front-page-logo" type="image/svg+xml" data="images/materialize.svg">
               Your browser does not support SVG
           </object>
         </a>
       </li>

       <li><a href="#!">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Materialize documentation for nav bar's I found the below code:

```
nav ul li {
    transition: background-color .3s;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
    transition: background-color .3s;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

On the first code snippet, you can see there's a 'float: left;' and on the second code snipped there's a 'display: inline-block'. Which sets the list items onto the same line.

To stop this you need to remove the float and amend the display to 'block' per my below example:

```
nav ul li {
    transition: background-color .3s;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
    transition: background-color .3s;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Without seeing all of your CSS, you may not need any 'display' property on your nav ul a, as it's a standard list attribute.